# Material UI Grid doesn't strecth to full parent height

Tags: html, css, next.js, material-ui

I am using Next.js and Material UI for a project.

My issue is that When Im using Material UI grid it doesn't stretch to its parent full Height.

Here is my index.tsx code:

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import { useState } from 'react'

import Login from './login'

export default function Home() {
  const [isConnected, setIsConnected] = useState(false)
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <main style={{height: "100%", backgroundColor: "red"}}>
        {isConnected? "AAA" : <Login/>}
      </main>
    </>
  )
}
```

Here is my Login page code:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';

import styles from '../styles/Login.module.css'
import { Grid } from '@mui/material';
import { height } from '@mui/system';

interface LoginPageProps {
  // Props go here
}

interface LoginPageState {
  username: string;
  password: string;
}

const LoginPage: React.FC<LoginPageProps> = (props: LoginPageProps) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<LoginPageState>({
    username: '',
    password: '',
  });

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    if (name === 'username') {
      setState({ ...state, username: value });
    } else if (name === 'password') {
      setState({ ...state, password: value });
    }
  };

  const handleSignup = () => {
    // Handle signup here
  };

  const handleSignin = () => {
    // Handle signin here
  };

  return (
    <Grid container
      direction="row"
      justifyContent="center"
      alignItems="stretch" xs={12} sm={12} md={12}
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "green"
      }}
    >
      <Grid item md={6} 
      direction="column"
      >
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
          <Box
            className="form"
            component="form"
            sx={{
              height: "100%",
            }}
          >
            <div
            >
              <TextField
                label="Username"
                variant="outlined"
                name="username"
                value={state.username}
                onChange={handleChange}
                fullWidth
              />
              <TextField
                label="Password"
                variant="outlined"
                type="password"
                name="password"
                value={state.password}
                onChange={handleChange}
                fullWidth
                margin="normal"
              />
              <div />
              <Button className="signup" variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handleSignup}>
                Sign Up
              </Button>
              <Button className="signin" variant="contained" color="secondary" onClick={handleSignin}>
                Sign In
              </Button>
            </div>
          </Box>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={6} sm={6} md={6}>
        design
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default LoginPage;
```

Here is my global.css file and its the only styling not applied inline:

```
html, body, #__next {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Im adding an img to clarify my issue.

- red background is the main html tag - the parent
- green background is the grid material ui component - the child

[image]

how to make the green component (the child) stretch its entire parent height?

Comment: You could try setting the height: `height: "100vh"` on the green grid component.

Comment: While this works its a patch not a solution. It will happend again on its child component and it doesn't take into account the fact what if want to add padding on a higher level? now the page will have scroll even though the content only takes half the page

Comment: What layout exactly are you trying to achieve? You may also experiment with the `<Stack>` component instead of the `<Grid>`.